# Select jquery bootstrap display selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a `table` and when I click on a `tr` the values are transmitted it `input` elements and bootstrap `select-search` in order to edit them and submit updates.

My problem is that when jQuery sets a value in `console.log` it appears that the right value is selected but not displayed. The default value is always shown in select options.

```
$('#4 option').prop('selected', false)
    .filter('[value=' + $tds.eq(3).text() + ']')
    .prop('selected', true);
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2" id="4">
    <select style="width: 170px;" class="form-control search-select select-compte" >
        {% for compte in comptes %}
            <option value="{{compte.code}}">
                {{compte.code}} {{compte.description}}
            </option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Try just `$('#4 select').val($tds.eq(3).text())`.

Comment: If `select-search` is  a plugin you probably need to do update using plugin API

Comment: i tryed many types `            //$('#4').removeClass('search-select');
            //$('.select-compte').text($tds.eq(3).text());
            var valueSelect = $('#4').find('option[value='+$tds.eq(3).text()+']').text();
            $('#4 option[value='+$tds.eq(3).text()+']').attr('text',valueSelect);
            $('#4 option[value='+$tds.eq(3).text()+']').click();
            
           //$('#4 select').val($tds.eq(3).text());
           //$('#4 option:selected').text(""+$tds.eq(3).text());
           //$('#4').addClass('search-select');`

Comment: no select-search works fine